# Creating new columns in dataframe with incremently decreasing amount of rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am relatively new to R, and programming in general, and have a dataframe with two columns, such as:

```
X <- c(2010,2011,2012,2013,2014)
Y <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
DATA <- data.frame(X,Y)
```

Now I would  like to create a number of new columns equalling the number of rows minus one. The first newly created column should begin in row number two and each additional column should start one below the prior one (until the last column with one value is created).
The values should be taken from column Y one row above.

The desired output is as follows:

```
X <- c(2010,2011,2012,2013,2014)
Y <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
NEW_COLUMN_1 <- c(NA,1,2,3,4)
NEW_COLUMN_2 <- c(NA,NA,2,3,4)
NEW_COLUMN_3 <- c(NA,NA,NA,3,4)
NEW_COLUMN_4 <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,4)
DATA <- data.frame(X,Y,NEW_COLUMN_1,NEW_COLUMN_2,NEW_COLUMN_3,NEW_COLUMN_4)
```

As I said, I am new to R and have no idea how to start, so I would appreciate any help you may offer.

EDIT:

My question from above besides creating new columns was how to populate those new columns with values from column Y one row above. The problem was solved in a very efficient manner by @CPak (see below).

Since returning the values is based on the term " function(i) dplyr::lag(DATA$Y, i)", I'd be interested in whether the term could be replaced by a computation.

For example, would it be easily implementable to return for each data point in the newly-created columns the value from column Y in the same row divided by the value of column Y from the row one above the first cell of each newly-created column?

Let us, for example, take the first cell of NEW_COLUMN_1 (DATA[2,3]), whose value should be given by the value of column Y in the same row (DATA[2,2]: 2) divided by the value of column Y in the row one above the first cell of NEW_COLUMN_1 which would be (DATA[1,2]: 1).

As the above is certainly complicated, I provide beneath the coordinates for all cells:

```
X <- c(2010,2011,2012,2013,2014)
Y <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
NEW_COLUMN_1 <- c("NA","DATA[2,2]/DATA[1,2]","DATA[3,2]/DATA[1,2]","DATA[4,2]/DATA[1,2]","DATA[5,2]/DATA[1,2]")
NEW_COLUMN_2 <- c("NA","NA","DATA[3,2]/DATA[2,2]","DATA[4,2]/DATA[2,2]","DATA[5,2]/DATA[2,2]")
NEW_COLUMN_3 <- c("NA","NA","NA","DATA[4,2]/DATA[3,2]","DATA[5,2]/DATA[3,2]")
NEW_COLUMN_4 <- c("NA","NA","NA","NA","DATA[5,2]/DATA[4,2]")
DATA <- data.frame(X,Y,NEW_COLUMN_1,NEW_COLUMN_2,NEW_COLUMN_3,NEW_COLUMN_4)
```

The final result should then yield:

```
X <- c(2010,2011,2012,2013,2014)
Y <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
NEW_COLUMN_1 <- c(NA,2,3,4,5)
NEW_COLUMN_2 <- c(NA,NA,1.5,2,2.5)
NEW_COLUMN_3 <- c(NA,NA,NA,1.33,1.67)
NEW_COLUMN_4 <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,1.25)
DATA <- data.frame(X,Y,NEW_COLUMN_1,NEW_COLUMN_2,NEW_COLUMN_3,NEW_COLUMN_4)
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the new columns using `lapply` and `dplyr::lag`. The resulting list is bound together using `Reduce("cbind", ...)` and converted to a data.frame/tibble, and given column names using `setNames`

```
library(tidyverse)
newcols <- Reduce("cbind", lapply(1:(nrow(DATA)-1), function(i) dplyr::lag(DATA$Y, i))) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  setNames(paste0("NEW_COLUMN_", 1:ncol(.)))
cbind(DATA, newcols)

     # X Y NEW_COLUMN_1 NEW_COLUMN_2 NEW_COLUMN_3 NEW_COLUMN_4
# 1 2010 1           NA           NA           NA           NA
# 2 2011 2            1           NA           NA           NA
# 3 2012 3            2            1           NA           NA
# 4 2013 4            3            2            1           NA
# 5 2014 5            4            3            2            1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @CPak, the solution works great! So the part "function(i) dplyr::lag(DATA$Y, i)))" returns the values. 
Would it have to be written materially differently to make a computation out of the term? 
For example, (the value of the same row divided by the value of row 1 (both from column X) divided by (the value of the same row divided by the value of row 1 (both from column Y)?
Sorry if the question may seem basic but I am struggling with some stuff I believe should be quite straight-forward based on how easy it is being done in Excel...

Comment: Sorry I'm not understanding what you want to do as part of your more complex calculation. Could you edit your original post (add **Edit**, then ...) to describe the operation and what you expect as output?

Comment: Thank you, @CPak, for your feedback! I adjusted my original post accordingly and hope that I managed to make myself clearer. Sorry, nonetheless, for the complicated question...